# Performance issue with Chrome extension (websocket + redux)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, redux

I have a websocket connection with a lot of messages, and a background whose state is managed by Redux. After I open and close my extension a few times, it starts lagging a lot. I am trying to solve the performance issue by only having the websocket open while the popup is active. Please look at the code below.

**popup component**

```
  componentDidUnmount() {
    this.port.disconnect();
  }

  componentDidMount() {    
    this.port = chrome.runtime.connect();
  }
```

**background**

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener((port) => {
  console.log("Connected!")

  window.sockets.push(openSocket());

  port.onDisconnect.addListener(() => {
    console.log("Disconnected!")

    window.sockets.forEach(socket => {
      socket.close();
    })

    window.sockets = [];
  });
});
```

**openSocket()**

```
function openSocket() {
  const socket = new WebSocket("wss://some/websocket")

  socket.onmessage = (event) => {
    store.dispatch(some(info));
  }

  return socket;
}
```

This works fine **unless** you open/close the popup more than a couple of times. The background fails to capture the `disconnect` event from the popup. One possible problem is that since I'm updating the redux store on every single websocket message, which is coming in with a rate of 1000 msgs/sec, background thread is "clogged."

Comment: `1000 msgs/sec` means 1ms per message so I doubt it's a sufficient time budget to process a message. Try using web workers.

Comment: the rate might actually be lower than that, maybe 50~100 msgs/sec. The component renders fine. It's just that when I open/close the extension a few times, it starts lagging a lot and becomes un-usable after that.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Check if it was reported on https://crbug.com or submit a new report with a simple demo extension that reproduces the bug.